# Google Sign in Button from Flutter causes a FATAL exception

Tags: flutter, google-signin

Ihave an app that I'm developing that uses firebase-auth Google sign-in button. This functionality was working, but at sometime since last few flutter upgrades it now causes a FATAL exception.

The top line of the exception shows as

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;

It appears to be somesort of conflict between  versions of  Flutter and/or flutter libraries included.

Any help would be gratefully accepted

Simon

I have fluttter functionality currently running only on Android, that calls

final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

this line triggers a FATAL exception, which causes the app to fail immediately.

Comment: have you added `SHA-1` Key into Firebase?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.